# Why are certain "pointer states" stable under decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Is it simply a brute fact that certain pointer states are more robust? Are there any philosophical investigations into why these are the states that nature prefers?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly  Elaborate...? I am really trying to understand why we observe individual points when a particle hits a detector screen rather than some superposition of points. The explanation I hear is that these are the states that are "stable" somehow. Please correct me if there is a better way to conceptualize this.

Comment: Thank you. I'm mostly interested in many-worlds anyway. Perhaps my confusion all comes down to the idea you mentioned that interactions are local. When we say this, does it mean that despite the particle being spread out over space (assuming the wavefunction has some physical reality) it always interacts at a single location?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly So I guess my question is why the particle is never able to be seen interacting at more than one location, given that it interacts with all locations. In the many-worlds interpretation I'm wondering: why do each of the branches form so that there is only one dot on the screen. Why can't there be a branch where there are two dots or something?

Comment: Or maybe stated a different way. Let's say there are just two locations on the screen that can be hit. The particle will be in a superposition of hitting each of the two locations, but couldn't we also add a term for the possibility of hitting both locations? Why are we forced to break the wavefunction into the possibility of hitting each location separately?

Comment: For something like spin I guess it makes more intuitive sense that the particle has to choose one or the other, but I guess the question remains. Why can't the "Spin Up AND Down" particle interact in some additional way? It seems like the particle has special ways that it likes to branch the wavefunction when measured, and my question is where do these special states come from? (Am I correct in saying these are the eigenstates of a particular basis)

Comment: I'm sure there's something dumb I'm just not getting, but maybe I'm thinking something like this... is there a reason you could never have an initial state like |x + y, 0⟩  that evolves into |x + y, x + y⟩? In other words, a state where the particle is in both locations and evolves into a state where it is detected at both locations.

Comment: Thank you! I think I am starting to get it. I think I failed to realize that the position operator separates the wavefunction into individual locations *by design*. I was stuck on trying to figure out why we couldn't design a different operator that could potentially describe the particle as being in multiple locations at once, but now I see that it is simply because that wouldn't fit with experiment.

Comment: You're welcome! (By the way, I deleted my previous comments because they're no longer needed.)